# Saving an existing docx document does not change the filename

Tags: python, pdf, python-docx

I want to open an existing docx document, make some changes to it and then save it as a new one with a different filename. Then I convert this docx file to pdf and open it with Adobe Acrobat Reader.
But instead of my new filename, Adobe shows me
[this file name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36O5L.png) "Microsoft Word - Dokument1" instead of "test".
The windows explorer shows me the right filename. But it is not Adobe's fault because when I open the new docx file and save it as pdf, the right name will be displayed.
The word_to_pdf function seems to me also working fine because when I am converting a "self-created" docx file to pdf via this function, the correct name will be also shown.
So the problem is probably the docx library which is not saving the new document correctly.

```
import os
import comtypes.client
from docx import Document

def word_to_pdf(_in, _out):
    pdf_format_key = 17
    file_in = os.path.abspath(_in)
    file_out = os.path.abspath(_out)
    worddoc = comtypes.client.CreateObject("Word.Application")
    doctemp = worddoc.Documents.Open(file_in)
    doctemp.SaveAs(file_out, FileFormat=pdf_format_key)
    doctemp.close()
    worddoc.Quit()


doc = Document("C:/Users/myname/Desktop/20210501.docx")
doc.save("test.docx")
word_to_pdf("test.docx", "test.pdf")
```

Comment: Test your hypothesis by running `word_to_pdf("C:/Users/.../20210501.docx", "test.pdf")` and leaving `python-docx` entirely out of it. I think you'll find you get the same results.

Comment: Tested with a docx file generated by python docx --> does not work.
Tested with a docx file which I have edited with MS-Word and have saved it normaly--> does work!